# More than one layout for a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, layout

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
class SimulationController < ApplicationController
  layout "generic", :only => [:login, :invalid]
  layout "menubar", :except => [:login, :invalid]
```

For some reason, my `login` page still uses the menubar layout (I can tell because a menu bar will appear at the top). If I comment out the 3rd line, the menu bar will disappear. So it seems like both layouts are being applied one after another.

But if I comment out the `layout "generic"`bit, I will it will be just black and white, meaning no CSS style sheet is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this ticket, your problem seems to be similar: 
[http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/8867]

Answer (score 5):

You look like you're trying to apply different layouts under different run-time conditions. The simplest way to tackle this is using a method reference for the layout.

For example: -

```
class ResourceController < ActionController::Base
  layout :choose_layout

  private
    def choose_layout    
      if [ 'signup', 'login' ].include? action_name
        'login_layout'
      else
        'admin_layout'
      end
    end
```

Check out the Rails [API reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods.html) for ActionController::Layout under the heading "Types of Layout"

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is actually within your actions.

```
def login
  render :action => "login", :layout => "generic"
end
```

You could also make the actual "menubar" html a partial and turn the rendering off under certain conditions.